# Time to get Canada Visit visa

Tags: canada, tourist-visas

I filled an application for Canada visit visa on June 10th. Given that im in the US now and on a B1 visa, i read on the internet that it takes no more than a week to get Canada visit visa if applying from the US.

But i still haven't received any update from Canada immigration. Just a message the day after applying that my application has been received and in process.

Can someone tell if they have had a similar predicament and how long did it take to finally get the visa.
Many thanks!

Answer (score 3):

As the 10th was Sunday and not a business day, it's been 6 1/2 days. You're having what some here refer to as a bit of post-submission anxiety.

The CIC [processing times calculator](http://www.cic.gc.ca/english/information/times/) estimates that it would take 14 days (visitor visa, applying from outside Canada, applying from within the US), not including transit time between the VAC and IRCC office.