# Canada transit visa online application

Tags: canada, transit-visas

I have submitted an online application for a Canadian transit visa on 5 July 2018. I am an Indian passport holder and applied from Mumbai. I would like to know when I can expect to get my visa?

Also, as I submitted the application online, do I have to submit my passport physically to get a transit visa stamp?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You've asked two questions, both of which have previous answers here: [wait time for visa](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/117055/time-to-get-canada-visit-visa) and [need to submit passport](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/58474/canada-transit-visa-will-i-need-to-submit-my-passport-or-does-it-come-electron)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Canada Transit Visa - Will I need to submit my passport or does it come electronically?](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/58474/canada-transit-visa-will-i-need-to-submit-my-passport-or-does-it-come-electron) and [Time to get Canada visa](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/117055/time-to-get-canada-visit-visa)